# Windows NT Version

Tags: windows-xp

Fix for rpcrt4.dll was given in Windows NT 4.0. I got this from a KB article. How to check my Windows NT Version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

1. Open a Command Window and type "ver" and hit Enter.
2. Right Click "My Computer" and click on Properties.

Comment: But that is Windows XP version, right? Is this the NT version?
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]

Comment: Windows XP (5.1) is the successor to Windows 2000 (NT 5.0). If you are looking for NT 4.0 specifically then you probably mean the Service Pack version which you can find using method 2.

Answer (score -1):

Type "winver" in the run program accessed in the start menu.